# ASP.NET dynamic content AdSense question

Tags: c#, asp.net, adsense

I was wondering, if I create a page e.g. index.aspx and I create it's contents based on a variable, would an AdSense block always show the same ad? Meaning is there a way to give it a dynamic content and having the ad addept to the content without creating a page for each content.

For example I have a site with 3 links: pears, apples and lemons. I have a database which has the content of each page. I have a dynamic page index.aspx which modifies it's content based on the clicked link (the link always returns to index.aspx). If I want an ad to match my content, should I then do  it differently? Like creating pages for each link and adding the content to each page dynamicly based on the link or something?

Thannks in advance

Comment: Maybe try SuperUser, or the AdSense documentation? It sounds like more a question about how AdSense works rather than about ASP .NET...

Answer (score 0):

> an AdSense block always show the same ad
>   **No - its show ads, depending on your test found on your page.**

In every view of your page, just before adSense show the ads, is reading your page for find from your text on your page, what ads is going to show.

So from the moment your content page is depends from the url (and not from session, or other hidden fields) then adSense is show ads depends from what you have as content on your pages.

Because the first time adSense make some tests, or cache your pages, or I do not know what, give adSense some time and you see that ads is depends from your content.